# Use Composer to execute a composer.json file

Tags: php, composer-php, silverstripe

I have downloaded a SilverStripe theme, that contains a file called composer.json, inside there is a script to download several silverstripe elements. I have installed composer onto my Mac, and can load it up by typing 'composer' into terminal. How do I now get composer to run the composer.son file I have so it'll download all my extra elements to build my site with this template?

Comment: `composer install` from within the directory where `composer.json` exists.

Comment: I'm still running into problems. If I have the composer.json file in Macintosh HD/template what do I actually need to type into terminal?

Comment: Have you installed composer globally ?

Comment: if composer.lock file exists - just run `php composer install`, if composer.json only - `php composer update`